# Enunciate error: cannot access com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.AbstractHttpContextInjectable

Tags: java, rest, web, jersey, enunciate

We are using enunciate v2.8.0 for generating docs in our project. Also, we use Jersey 2 (org.glassfish.jersey v2.5.1).

While building REST module, enunciate maven plugin falls down with error

"**error: cannot access com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.AbstractHttpContextInjectable**"

I guess, it means that enunciate uses Jersey1 and tries to find it in our project, because, when we had Jersey1 dependency - it worked fine. Also, enunciate inside has both Jersey1 and Jersey2 dependencies.
Now I cannot find information about how to switch enunciate for using Jersey2.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue ?

Comment: @RahulVashishta, yes, but it was a long time ago, so if I'm not mistaken in enunciate config file (`enunciate.xml`) there is smth like `<jackson1 disabled="true"/>`. I had problems with Jackson1.
Try to look in that direction

Answer (score 0):

Adding: `<jaxrs disabled="true" />`to enunciate.xml worked for me.